# ASP.NET Core Newtonsoft Json length issue

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application and I'm trying to return a long `JSON` object. However inspecting the response i see only half of my list.

I already specified some default configuration in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(option =>
    {
        option.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        option.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

In ASP.NET MVC5 you could use `JavaSerializer` and specify the length property.

How can I achieve that using ASP.NET Core?

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FilteredData);
```

Comment: Sure you don't receive an exception in the middle of the serialization? Does the request return status code 200 or some of the 500-ish codes?

Comment: No. Serializing in C# using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FilteredData)` is fine but when returning the the result with `return Json(FilteredData)` i got half the serialization.

Comment: @osiris_v6 same problem here ! Have you find any solution ?